# Facebook share button not posting to wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I need to publish URL with Cutsom text on facebook. I am using the following string to publish to facebook wall:

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=This is the dummy text&p[summary]=This is the dummy summary&p[url]=www.google.com`

It open facebook window and displays the message and link on that page but when I click on share button, a message pops up saying `Could not post to wall`. How do I resolve that issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [url] parameter is malformed. Try adding `http://`